# What to build `git` from source without `git-svn`?

Tags: git, build

Is it possible to build `git` from source without `git-svn`?

I know how to build `git` in general, but I could not find any way to disable building `git-svn` in `./configure --help`.

Currently, I am using the following command to build `git` without the SVN tests which take to long:

```sh
NO_SVN_TESTS=1 make -j4 profile all doc info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-svn` is internally running a perl script `git-svn.perl`.

You should be able to disable `git-svn` by commenting this line `SCRIPT_PERL += git-svn.perl` in the `MakeFile`.

Note:

- If `NO_PERL` is set, then git will be built without support for the perl scripts which include functionalities like `git-add--interactive`, `git-archimport`, `git-cvsexportcommit`, `git-cvsimport`, `git-cvsserver`, `git-send-email` and `git-svn` (this list is as per git *v2.26.2*, you can find the list of perl scripts by running `make build-perl-script`)
- If only some perl scripts are required (in this case all scripts other than `git-svn`), you can set `SCRIPT_PERL` to all scripts other than `git-svn.perl`

  ```
  SCRIPT_PERL="git-add--interactive.perl git-archimport.perl git-cvsexportcommit.perl git-cvsimport.perl git-cvsserver.perl git-send-email.perl"
  ```

  List of perl scripts can be obtained as noted in point 1.

  The make commands will look like this :

  ```
  make SCRIPT_PERL="git-add--interactive.perl git-archimport.perl git-cvsexportcommit.perl git-cvsimport.perl git-cvsserver.perl git-send-email.perl"
  make SCRIPT_PERL="git-add--interactive.perl git-archimport.perl git-cvsexportcommit.perl git-cvsimport.perl git-cvsserver.perl git-send-email.perl" install
  ```

Comment: Just a note to future passers-by: I’ve built it this script of mine: [git_src.sh](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/-/blob/master/bash_progs/git_src.sh)